# Dialog plugin buttonlabels as image

Tags: javascript, android, dialog, cordova-plugins

Right now my code is:

```
navigator.notification.confirm(
data.message, // message
 onConfirm,            // callback to invoke with index of button pressed
data.title,           // title
['No','Yes']     // buttonLabels
);
```

How can i replace the 'Yes' and 'No' buttonLabels with images? This code is referenced from https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-dialogs/